Best practices for working with worker and Flow
I'm working on an application that uses WorkerManager for background tasks, most of the time it's used to send requests to the backend and process the received data, I thought it would be a great idea to use LiveData (or Flow) to automatically update UI after new data is saved to the database, but it doesn't work as i expected, the flow does not emit data after it saved to the db
In my background worker, I have an async method that loads the data to backend after the user clicks the "save" button.
override suspend fun doWorkWithRetry(): Result = coroutineScope {
    val one = processCreatedReceipts()
    if (one.await() * other async methods *) {
        Result.success()
    } else {
        throw RuntimeException("Failed to upload data")
    }
}
@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
private fun processCreatedReceipts() = GlobalScope.async {
    val data: List<Expenses> = expensesRepo.findAllBySyncState(SyncState.UNSYNCED)
    data.parallelStream().forEach { expense ->
        val dto = expense.asCreateDto()
        expensesService.createReceipt(dto).run { r, t ->
            t?.let {
                expensesRepo.updateSyncStateById(expense.id, SyncState.SYNC_FAILED)
                throw RuntimeException("Data sync failed with error: ${t.message}")
            }
            r?.data?.result?.let { result ->
                 * save to received data to db *
            }
        }
    }
}

From the UI I get the list of data as a flow using this method in the DAO object
@Query(
        """
        SELECT *
        FROM files
        WHERE resourceId == :id and sync_state is not 'PENDING_DELETE'
        """
    )
    abstract fun findByIdFlow(id: String?): Flow<List<FileData>>

I create a Flow inside a Fragments viewModel using
val list: Flow<List<FileData>> = repo.findByIdFlow(userId)

And I collect data in a fragment using
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    viewModel.list.collect {         
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {             
            * update UI *         
        }     
    }
}

Could this be a problem with the async methods what saved data to db or am I getting the data from db in wrong way?

how/where are you observing/collecting the flow?

@tyczj I create flow in viewModel fragments
val list: Flow<List<ExpensesWithFile>> = repo.findWithFile(userId)
I collect data inside fragment in that way
    viewModel.list.collect {
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            * update UI method *
        }
    }
}```

please edit the question, do not put the code in your comment
